# Haskell - Sum values in a tree

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

My tree looks like this, a tree which at each node can or cannot have an integer:

```
data Tree = Empty | Node (Maybe Integer) Tree Tree deriving Show
```

I want to sum all the values in the tree, not including Nothing values and if tree is not empty but has only Nothing values, just return Nothing, or empty tree is 0. These cases I understand how to.

I want thinking depth first traversal would be best, or just some basic traversal in general, but struggling on how to implement it elegantly.

treeValues :: Tree -> Maybe Integer

Comment: What's supposed to happen if some nodes are nothing? Clarify!

Comment: Ah forget to mention, I edited the question above. It just ignores the nothing values.

Comment: The fact that a tree of nothings is treated one way and an empty tree another way feels rather awkward. I think those really should both be 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already know how to sum lists, so you could transform your tree into a list first:

```
> toList :: Tree -> [Integer]
> toList Empty        = []
> toList (Node a l r) = maybeToList a ++ toList l ++ toList r
>   where maybeToList (Just x) = [x]
>         maybeToList Nothing  = []
```

Now, you want to differ between an empty tree (`Empty`) and a tree that contains only `Nothing`. Since `toList` filters all `Nothing` values, this boils down to

```
> sumTree :: Tree -> Maybe Integer
> sumTree Empty = Just 0
> sumTree tree  = case toList tree of
>                  [] -> Nothing      -- all values in the tree are Nothing
>                  xs -> Just $ sum xs       -- some were Just x
```

### But wait, there's more!

`sumTree` isn't that nice yet. What if we want to compute the product of a `Tree`? Hm. Well, we can take a tree, transform it to a list, and use… a folding function!

```
> type I = Integer -- otherwise the lines get ridiculously long
>
> foldrTree' :: (I -> I -> I) -> I -> Tree -> Maybe I
> foldrTree' _ init Empty = init
> foldrTree' f init tree  = case toList tree of
>                            [] -> Nothing
>                            xs -> Just $ foldr f init xs
> --                                      ^^^^^
```

Now we can take any `(Integer -> Integer -> Integer)` and produce a single value, as long as our operation is associative:

```
> productTree :: Tree -> Maybe Integer
> productTree = foldrTree' (*) 1
>
> sumTree' :: Tree -> Maybe Integer
> sumTree' = foldrTree' (+) 0
```

Comment: In terms of my [hint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28894678/414413), `toList = reduce (\x l r -> maybeToList x ++ l ++ r) []`.

Comment: @Cirdec: Yep. Didn't see your answer. Thanks for the comment, otherwise I would have written a completely fledged `instance Foldable => TreeF` tutorial – again.

Comment: I want to simply make a call to toList, and then sumTree, in my main function. How do I nest the functions calls nicely, like                           treeValues :: Tree -> Maybe Integer                                                                             treeValues = I want to call toList and sumTree together in a elegant way, first calling toList then sumTree?

Answer (score 6):

You can make your Tree a [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Foldable.html) instance, and you get many functions for free, including `sum`:

> sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a Source
>
> The sum function computes the sum of the numbers of a structure.

But you need to make your `Tree` a parametric type:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node (Maybe a) Tree Tree
```

Also, with GHC 7.10, almost all Prelude functions will use `Foldable` and `Traversable` typeclasses instead of lists, and then you can use them freely for your tree, if you implement those typeclasses.

Comment: The `Foldable` instance can be derived automatically by GHC with [`DeriveFoldable`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html)(Section 7.5.3).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hint:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

reduce :: (a -> r -> r -> r) -> r -> Tree a -> r
reduce f z = go
    where
        go Empty        = z
        go (Node x l r) = f x (go l) (go r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the above solutions and comments plus [lyah](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers) and [Brent Yorgeys advice](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/deriving-pleasure-from-ghc-6-12-1/) I compiled the following proposal (try as you might like in `ghci`):

```
:set -XDeriveFoldable -XDeriveFunctor
:m + Data.Foldable Data.Monoid
data Tree a = Empty | Node (Maybe a) (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable)
let tree :: Tree Integer ; tree = Node Nothing (Node (Just 42) Empty Empty) (Node Nothing Empty Empty)
foldMap Sum tree
```

It though returns only `0` in both cases only `Nothing` values given and tree is `Empty` but I hope it gives a hint later for learners like me.