# Calling Helper functions within functions - Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have 3 functions, the first one is a

```
toList :: Tree -> [Integer]
```

the second is

```
sumTree :: Tree -> Maybe Integer
```

which sums a the elements in a tree, filtering for some edge cases. My main function is

```
treeSum :: Tree -> Maybe Integer
```

which I want to call the toList on the input to Tree then call sumTree on the output of the previous call. I don't know how to structure it together elegantly. What I did was

```
treeSum = sumTree (toList x)
```

but I am getting `x` not in scope.

Comment: Because `x` is not defined.  You probably want `treeSum` to take `x` as an argument, which in Haskell is written `treeSum x = ...`.  Exercise: what will the type of `x` be?

Comment: Ah oops. So I tried, treeSum  x = sumTree (toList x), isn't working too

Comment: The type of x will be a Maybe Integer, my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Haskell is telling you by saying `Not in scope` is that `x` is defined nowhere else.

You should write something like:

```
treeSum x = sumTree (toList x)
```

The problem you will then face is a type error. `toList` takes a `Tree` and returns a `List` of `Integer` but `sumTree` is waiting for a `Tree`, not a list of `Integer`.

To be honest, What you’re trying to do is not really clear.

Note: you should avoid having both `sumTree` and `treeSum` defined in your code because you will loose yourself and everyone who will try and read your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894252/haskell-sum-values-in-a-tree trying to do this question really.

Comment: With all the answers you get for that previous question, it's even less clear what you miss to achieve your goal. Have you seen that http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Foldable.html gives an example that nearly does what you want to do ?

Comment: Could you give examples of trees you will be working on and what you expect the functions to return ?